# What should I use to communicate data between forms/controls in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, communication

I am working on a simple task app that uses windows forms. 
 WPF might be better toolwise, but I just don't want to use a technology that uses GPU acceleration just to render something transparently. I think its idiotic.

My problem is as follows: I have a main windows which contains a series of controls. At the press of a button, another form is shown (with ShowDialog) in which I can create a task. Pressing save, adds the task to the main form's listbox where all tasks are shown. Right now,all the communication is done via button click events (mostly). I would like to have something more elegant, like a communication interface between the dialogs.

EX: When I create the task, I want to automatically assign it to a project (which is probably going to be a an array containing all the tasks) and at the same time add it to the aforementioned list & have it acessible from memory. I am not sure how to achieve this, as using collections and arrays to manipulate, feels a bit impossible & overly complicated. I had seen some people suggest using delegates, data binding and interfaces. But I don't know exactly how they can be used and MSDN documentation is just impossibly difficult to read.

I think something similar to this: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sgMoNSNLLvg might be of use to me, but I'm not sure how to implement it. Also, thinking of saving the app settings/state into a file. I've seen XML, App.Config and whatnot. My app plans to be portable, which means that either saving its settings into the %user% app settings folder, or something similar. BTW: Not learning for an exam or something, just building an app to learn by myself. I'm actually a UI designer. ;)

Comment: Additional information: the app has 3 windows. View task/edit task, Create task and the main window that spawns both of them.

Comment: WPF is not about "eye candy" - it's about DataBinding and customization and actually being able to do something useful without resorting to bunch of horrible hacks and without having your application code tied to the UI. And yes, WPF is much better for decoupled communication and the like. winforms only has `Button_Click` type of stuff.

Comment: I am well aware of the advantages, since I've been working with WPF for the biggest part of the last 3 years, but I am also aware of its drawbacks, especially performance wise. However, at this stage I'm not hellbent on using either one or the other, which is why I'll be doing some testing. Considering the app is more for my own self than a publicly available app, I might do with WPF just for the sake of working less. :)